# MAX date in same ID - calculated column DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I'm trying to create a calculated column that should returns 2nd, 3rd, 4th min value as shows below for the same group ID. Can someone help me on this.

[image]

Comment: does [this](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Lead-and-Lag-in-DAX/m-p/649162) answer your question